# Global variable discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot (.py) and am wondering how to set/change global variables between functions.
Code:

```
team = 0

@bot.command()
async def scrim(ctx, *, team):
    m1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    m7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name="Scrim Partner Hub") 
    sendchannel = await bot.fetch_channel(847285450820812850)
    if ctx.channel == sendchannel:
        ticket = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{team} scrim", category=category)

        embedVar = discord.Embed(color=0xcfe2f3)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f'{team} scrim.', value='This is a channel made specifically for this scrim. When done, report the score with !report.', inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name='Maplist (optional):', value=f'''
Match 1: {m1} Splat Zones
Match 2: {m2} Rainmaker
Match 3: {m3} Tower Control
Match 4: {m4} Clam Blitz
Match 5: {m5} Splat Zones
Match 6: {m6} Rainmaker
Match 7: {m7} Tower Control
''', inline=False)
        return await ticket.send(embed=embedVar)

@bot.command(case_insensitive = True, aliases = ["report", "close"])
async def end(ctx, score, *, team):
        category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name="Scrim Partner Hub")
        sendchannel = await bot.fetch_channel()
        if ctx.channel.catogory == category:
                embedVar = discord.Embed(color=0xcfe2f3)
                embedVar.add_field(name=f'{team} VS _____.', value=f'''
Score: {score}
Team: {team}
        ''', inline=False)
                await sendchannel.send(embed=embedVar)
                return await ctx.channel.delete()
```

I am hoping to pass a variable to the end command through input on the `!scrim` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `global` variables:

```py
var = 0

@bot.command()
async def t1(ctx):
    global var
    var += 1
    await ctx.send(var)


@bot.command()
async def t2(ctx):
    global var
    var += 2
    await ctx.send(var)
```

or `bot` instance that will hold your variable:

```py
bot.var = 0

@bot.command()
async def t1(ctx):
    bot.var += 1
    await ctx.send(bot.var)


@bot.command()
async def t2(ctx):
    bot.var += 2
    await ctx.send(bot.var)
```